# Ways for drivers to exchange data with userspace

Tags: drivers

I have two questions:

(A) I am trying to identify the various options available for a Linux device driver to exchange data with userspace.

A common approach I am aware of is `copy_from_user()` and `copy_to_user()`. From the [question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/320056/56644) on SO, some other options include `netlink`, `ioctl`, `sysfs`, `procfs`, `configfs`. I want to ask if anyone is aware of any resource where a complete list of options is described along with when it is appropriate to use these options.

(B) I also have the question of whether the type of driver in Linux has anything to do with options allowed to exchange data with user space.

Based on searching online, I can identify the drivers types as Character, Block, PCI, USB, Network, TTY (not sure if this list is complete). I want to ask whether there is any relation between type of driver and way to exchange data with user space OR are they independent ?

Comment: Define "the type of driver in Linux"

Comment: When I check online the category of driver I find are Character, Block, PCI, USB, Network

Comment: Think. Are these categories sounds orthogonal? Can't a network card Driver be usb? Since obviously you can buy a USB NIC or PCIe NIC. A driver is mostly a kernel module, as code running in kernel mode, it can do anything to exchange data with userspace code. If a path doesn't exist, then it can create it. Unlike userspace code is restricted by the kernel, kernel mode code, (running in Ring0, if x86) is only limited by CPU.

Answer (score 0):

Actually `copy_from_user()` and `copy_to_user()` - we can find these APIs in character driver. We can use sysfs attributes to share the data kernel to user space.